# Help manipulating algebraic expression to reach a goal

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to manipulate this expression

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\left(1+a\right)^{k}-\left(-a\right)^{k}+\left(1+a\right)^{k-1}-\left(-a\right)^{k-1}\right)$

Into this one:

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\left(1+a\right)^{k+1}-\left(-a\right)^{k+1}\right)$

Where a is:

$a=\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$

I have been at this for well over two hours just shifting things around with algebra to no avail. I have tried substituting the given value in for $a$, and have tried just keeping $a$ as a variable. I feel like I am just going in circles algebraically and never going to reach the conclusion without a new strategy.

So I ask: Can someone please help me get on the right track? Are there any techniques that tend to help out in situations like these? Perhaps a specific strategy? Also, is there a name for specific algebra problems like this, so I can practice or read something to help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, notice that $a^2 = \left(\dfrac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}\right)^2 = \dfrac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}=1-a\Rightarrow a^2+a-1=0\\\Rightarrow(1+a)^2=1+2a+a^2=2+a.$

Second, factor out $(1+a)^{k-1}$ and $(-a)^{k-1}.$

Doing so yields $\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}((1+a)^{k-1}(1+(1+a))-(-a)^{k-1}(1-a))=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}((1+a)^{k-1}(1+a)^2-(-a)^{k-1}(-a)^2)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}((1+a)^{k+1}-(-a)^{k+1})$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $a^2+a-1=0$. Therefore $2+a=(1+a)^2$ and $1-a=a^2$.

Then

$\left(1+a\right)^{k}+\left(1+a\right)^{\left(k-1\right)}=(1+a+1)\left(1+a\right)^{\left(k-1\right)}=\left(1+a\right)^{\left(k+1\right)}$

and

$\left(-a\right)^{k}+\left(-a\right)^{\left(k-1\right)}=(-a+1)\left(-a\right)^{\left(k-1\right)}=\left(-a\right)^{\left(k+1\right)}$

I hope it's all obvious now.